# A way to update data in the database without deleting earlier ones in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have ManyToMany relation in my model and the whole issue is how to only insert a new record (not repleace old one). I mean before update I have for example '1' in this field and after upade it will be '1, 2' instead of only '2' where 1 and 2 are id of other stuff in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `instance.relation.add(other_instance)`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/